# Staying in one place when the new elements are added to the beginning of the div

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am writing a chat page. Here I have a div which is the message container. When the user scrolls up, it sends a request to the server and receives older messages and adds them to the beginning of the message container. The problem is that when messages are added, the scrolling location of the user suddenly changes and jumps to another place.
get messages function:

```
this.$refs.messages.addEventListener("scroll", () => { //add event listener to messages container
    if (this.$refs.messages.scrollTop < 90) {
        this.loadingGetMoreMessages = true 
        this.getMoreMessages() // get older messages and add them in all messages array
    }
})
```

Vue structure:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column gap-2 h-100 w-100 pt-3" style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden"
ref="messages">
    <div v-for="(message, index) in chat.messages" :key="index">
        <div :class="{ 'message-container': true, 'flex-row-reverse': !message.yours }"
            :ref="'m-' + message.message_id">
            <div class="d-flex gap-2" :style="{ 'padding-right': !message.yours ? '20px' : '' }">
                <div :class="{ 'your-message': message.yours, 'its-message': !message.yours }">
                    {{ message.message }}
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center gap-2">
                        <i class="text-muted fi fi-br-check d-flex" v-if="!message.seen && message.yours"></i>
                        <i class="text-muted fi fi-br-check-double d-flex"
                            v-if="message.seen && message.yours"></i>
                        <p class="text-muted mt-1" style="font-size: .8rem"> {{ message.time }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is expected that adding new messages to the beginning of the div will not change the user's scroll position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the remaining distance to scroll to the *bottom* of the container. This is because if we want the scroll to be perceived as unchanged and we add messages above, then this bottom scroll distance should remain unchanged:

```js
const { scrollTop, scrollHeight } = this.$refs.messages;
const scrollBottom = scrollHeight - scrollTop;
```

Then, use `this.$nextTick` to wait for the DOM update from prepending the messages to change the scroll "bottom" position back to what we saved before:

```js
this.$nextTick(() => {
  this.$refs.messages.scrollTop = this.$refs.messages.scrollHeight - scrollBottom;
});
```

Live example:

```js
const { createApp } = Vue;

const app = createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      loadingGetMoreMessages: false,
      chat: {
        messages: Array(10)
          .fill()
          .map((_, i) => ({
            message_id: i,
            yours: false,
            seen: false,
            time: `09:${String(i).padStart(2, '0')}`,
            message: `Foo ${i}`,
          })),
      },
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.messages.scrollTop = 91;
 
    //add event listener to messages container
    this.$refs.messages.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      if (this.$refs.messages.scrollTop < 90) {
        this.loadingGetMoreMessages = true;
        // get older messages and add them in all messages array
        this.getMoreMessages()
      }
    })
  },
  methods: {
    getMoreMessages() {
      const { scrollTop, scrollHeight } = this.$refs.messages;
      const scrollBottom = scrollHeight - scrollTop;

      const { length } = this.chat.messages;
      this.chat.messages = Array(5)
        .fill()
        .map((_, i) => ({
          message_id: i + length,
          yours: false,
          seen: false,
          time: `09:${String(i).padStart(2, '0')}`,
          message: `Bar ${i}`,
        }))
        .concat(this.chat.messages);
      
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$refs.messages.scrollTop = this.$refs.messages.scrollHeight - scrollBottom;
      });
    }
  },
});

app.mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.3.4/vue.global.min.js" integrity="sha512-Wbf9QOX8TxnLykSrNGmAc5mDntbpyXjOw9zgnKql3DgQ7Iyr5TCSPWpvpwDuo+jikYoSNMD9tRRH854VfPpL9A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-t4GWSVZO1eC8BM339Xd7Uphw5s17a86tIZIj8qRxhnKub6WoyhnrxeCIMeAqBPgdZGlCcG2PrZjMc+Wr78+5Xg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div id="app" style="height: 200px">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column gap-2 h-100 w-100 pt-3" style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden" ref="messages">
    <div v-for="(message, index) in chat.messages" :key="index">
      <div :class="{ 'message-container': true, 'flex-row-reverse': !message.yours }" :ref="'m-' + message.message_id">
        <div class="d-flex gap-2" :style="{ 'padding-right': !message.yours ? '20px' : '' }">
          <div :class="{ 'your-message': message.yours, 'its-message': !message.yours }">
            {{ message.message }}
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center gap-2">
              <i class="text-muted fi fi-br-check d-flex" v-if="!message.seen && message.yours"></i>
              <i class="text-muted fi fi-br-check-double d-flex" v-if="message.seen && message.yours"></i>
              <p class="text-muted mt-1" style="font-size: .8rem"> {{ message.time }}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```